# Parsing a json tree in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I need to parse a json placed in a file and identify its structure below is the code where I tried doing that

```
var fs = require('fs')
var reqTemplate;
var obj;
fs.readFile('SampleData.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    reqTemplate = data;
    console.log('\nRequestTemplate:\n\n%s\n', reqTemplate);
    obj = JSON.parse(reqTemplate);
    var i = 0;
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        i++;
        console.log;
        console.log(key);
        console.log(obj[key]);
    });
});
```

The output that I got is:

```
{
    "AuthenticateUserReq": {
        "Tid": "123",
        "username": "131329",
        "password": "Vinod",
        "SessionTokenId": "",
        "DeviceInfo": {
            "DeviceName": "ABC",
            "DeviceVersion": "X",
            "UniqueDeviceID": "ZZZ",
            "Platform": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the parent key and its values.
I'm stuck as how to identify the child key and retrieval of its values.

PS: I wont be aware of the structure of the json response. I need to identify the root key and its value and also the children key and their values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate through the object manually?
Isn't the object you want simply `JSON.parse(reqTemplate)`?

Comment: @Cerbrus:That is just giving me the entire response.I want to get the individual keys and their values.

Comment: Ah, I see. Bergi's answer's the one then :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need recursion for [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal):

```
var callback = console.log;

function traverse(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
            if (typeof obj[i] == "object" && obj[i]) {
                callback(i);
                traverse(obj[i]);
            } else {
                callback(i, obj[i])
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && obj[prop]) {
                callback(prop);
                traverse(obj[prop]);
            } else {
                callback(prop, obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}

traverse( JSON.parse(reqTemplate) );
```

Comment: :Thanks i tried your solution and was able to come up with the required output.

Answer (score 2):

Might also want to try out Node traverse - https://github.com/substack/js-traverse.  Allows recursively walking a JSON tree to get each key value pair with context (ie: keeps track of parent), and can run map/reduce while traversing tree.  Very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse a JSON you get a normal JS object. You can obtain its keys by using `var keysOfObject = Object.keys(object);`. Then you can use those keys to get the values.

Comment: yup when i tried dat i am able to get oly the parent key say AuthenticateUserReq from  the above json.But i also want to get the DeviceInfo (ie)The main keys inside a parent key is not retrived in the above method

Comment: But what's your purpose? Why do you want to traverse the JSON? Looking for something? Or you just want to print it out?

Comment: I want to traverse the JSON store its keys in a db and also i should be able to bring back the json in its original formal by retrieving  its contents from the db